# Container with multiple instances of a jar having a class with static variables

Tags: java, static, jar, containers

I have a class A contained a static/singleton member called b.

This class in included in a jar  X, which appears at multiple locations.

My question is:

1. Are multiple copies of the jar X (and hence class A) present in the container having this codebase?
2. If so, whenever I have an assignment A.b = 10;, the b member of which copy of A will get the assignment? I currently have a problem that seems to be arising from this scenario, whereby even after setting the static variable to some value, I get a null value in another part of the code that reads it. What's the right "pattern" to follow to avoid/overcome this problem (assuming my diagnosis is correct)?

-KS

Comment: Depends on which ClassLoaders you are using and how they are set up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of an idea of what goes on with different `ClassLoader`s:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class StaticMemberTest {
    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // my .class files are in bin, relative to where I run the test from
        File f = new File("./bin");
        URL u = f.toURL();

        ClassLoader classLoader1 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { u }, null);
        ClassLoader classLoader2 = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { u }, null);

        Class class1 = classLoader1.loadClass("test.StaticMemberTest");
        System.out.println("class1=" + class1);
        System.out.println("class1.count=" + class1.getDeclaredField("count").get(null));

        Class class2 = classLoader2.loadClass("test.StaticMemberTest");
        System.out.println("class2=" + class2);
        System.out.println("class2.count=" + class2.getDeclaredField("count").get(null));

        class1.getDeclaredField("count").set(null, new Integer(99));

        System.out.println("class1.count=" + class1.getDeclaredField("count").get(null));
        System.out.println("class2.count=" + class2.getDeclaredField("count").get(null));

        System.out.println("class1.isAssignableFrom(class2)=" + class1.isAssignableFrom(class2));
        System.out.println("class2.isAssignableFrom(class1)=" + class2.isAssignableFrom(class1));

        Object ob1 = class1.newInstance();
        System.out.println("ob1=" + ob1);

        StaticMemberTest test = (StaticMemberTest) ob1;
    }
}
```

And the output

```
class1=class test.StaticMemberTest
class1.count=0
class2=class test.StaticMemberTest
class2.count=0
class1.count=99
class2.count=0
class1.isAssignableFrom(class2)=false
class2.isAssignableFrom(class1)=false
ob1=test.StaticMemberTest@35ce36
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: test.StaticMemberTest
    at test.StaticMemberTest.main(StaticMemberTest.java:37)
```

So you can see that the class names are the same, and both counts start off at zero. But you can set the static variable values independently.

Also, the `isAssignableFrom` tests show that the classes are not the same as far as the JVM is concerned.

And finally, when I try a cast that should work, it fails. Because the `ClassLoader` that loaded `class1` was *not* in the same `ClassLoader` hierarchy as the `ClassLoader` that was used to run the test. So the object `ob1` it created was not compatible with the `Class` of the test itself.